# PHP outputs a syntax error on one Shared Hosting and runs flawlessly on the other

Tags: php

I have an issue that is quite puzzling me.

I have a php script running on 2 different shared hostings.

On the first one everything runs flawlessly. On the second one it outputs me a syntax error and doesn't work.

Here is the syntax error and the code that is giving issues:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/click/public_html/extension/include/config.php on line 13
```

Code:

```
function pem2der($pem_data) {
return base64_decode(trim(explode('-----', $pem_data)[2]));
}
```

I can't seem to find the issue. Anyone could give me some help? Thanks in advance

Comment: because this method `explode('-----', $pem_data)[2]` not supported on older versions of PHP

Comment: check your php versions on all servers then compare the differences in them

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're doing [array dereferencing](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/138-Features-in-PHP-trunk-Array-dereferencing.html) which is only available in PHP as of version 5.4. You have it locally but your webhost does not. That's why you should always make sure your development environment matches your production environment.

Answer (score 0):

It because you're using something called array dereferencing which basically means that you can access a value from an array returned by a function direct. this is only supported in php>=5.4

To solve your issue, do something like this:

```
function pem2der($pem_data) {
    $exploded = explode('-----', $pem_data);
    $retStr = base64_decode(trim($exploded[2]));
    return $retStr;
}
```